# aws codepipeline notifications without SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

currently I'm sending notifications with sns, is it possible sending Email notifications without SNS in code-pipeline.?

Answer (score 2):

For human readable email notifications, the easiest way is to use the built-in notifications functionality.

To setup notifications for a pipeline go to the pipelines list, choose a pipeline, click notify at the top, and follow the wizard.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dtconsole/latest/userguide/notification-rule-create.html

Answer (score 1):

CodePipeline notifications are actually fulfilled by [CloudWatch events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html).

CloudWatch events supports a number of triggers, for sending emails a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function might be ideal when combined with [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) from the AWS SDK. You would of course need to format the email to your lining, as well as configuring SES for the sending domain you will be using.